# OSMnx - how to plot neighborhoods

Tags: osmnx

I'm trying plot just one neighborhood inside the Salvador City. I'd like to know if is possible separate the city in neighborhoods using the OSMnx. I need to get the statistics by neighborhoods.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If OSM has polygonal boundaries for the neighborhoods, you can get stats for each:

```py
import osmnx as ox
import pandas as pd
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

# add more neighborhood names for which OSM has polygonal boundaries
places = ['Barra, Salvador, Bahia']

stats = {}
for place in places:
    G = ox.graph_from_place(place, network_type='drive')
    stats[place] = ox.basic_stats(G)
pd.DataFrame(stats).T
```